# Using a method to start other methods in c#

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net

I want to be able to click 1 HTML button that that starts an event and have that event start lots of other events.

Example in Javascript you could do:

```
function prgStart() {
    DigitToWord_1()
    DigitToWord_2()
    DigitToWord_3()
}
```

I thought you would be able to do this in c#:

```
void prgStart(Object s, EventArgs e){
    DigitToWord_1();
    DigitToWord_2();
    DigitToWord_3();
}
```

However I cant seem to find how to do it in c# if there is a way

EDIT: Fixed now was just my bad deceleration of all the DigitToWord()'s wanting to many arguments.

Comment: What issues are you facing? Aren't these methods being called? What is the definition of `DigitToWord_1`?

Comment: Did you *try* your code? Did you get an error? Can you create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: just add a button and post back your action, very simple

Answer (score 1):

That's exactly how you would call additional methods from inside another method, assuming those methods are defined properly.

Comment: I just realised I had not declared all of the DigitToWord()'s correctly. Working now thanks for the help